# What data structure/database for fast counting?

Tags: java, database, data-structures, in-memory-database

I have 100M users and 10M items. A database (mysql) stores which items a user has clicked. On average, a user has clicked 15 items. Each user/item has an unique id which is a **long** number.


This is my problem:


- Given some items, i.e: *a,b,c*. And logic operators between them,i.e :

```
a AND b NOT c
```

(it means: the user clicked *a* AND *b* BUT did NOT click item *c*)


- Return how many users satisfied.

Response time **must be** in a few seconds.

The result does not need 100% accurate, but with a reasonable error.


What did I try:


Use Java HashMap to store the whole data on memory, and use some Java 8 stream APIs to count. It's really fast but needs synchronize with database. And it uses a lot of memory.

So, is there any in-memory database can do this counting above? I know Redis is an in-memory database but don't know how to store my data for this counting job.

And, the result does not need to be 100% accurate, is there any data structure which fasts and does not use a lot of memory?


**EDIT:**


As comments suggest I should use mysql database for queries.


This is my "small" table which has ~178M rows. A very simple query that count how many users clicked on item 1 takes 7.85 seconds. It is not too slow. But it seems not easy (for me) to build a very complicated logic query like

```
1 AND (2 OR (3 OR 4))
```

```
mysql> DESCRIBE user_item;                                                                                                                                                                                                                   +---------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field   | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| user_id | bigint(20) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| item_id | int(11)    | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
+---------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select TABLE_ROWS from information_schema.TABLES where table_name = 'user_item';
+------------+
| TABLE_ROWS |
+------------+
|  178611337 |
+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT COUNT(1) FROM `user_item` WHERE `item_id`=1;
+----------+
| COUNT(1) |
+----------+
| 33923046 |
+----------+
1 row in set (7.85 sec)
```

Comment: Why you don't use `sql`?

Comment: Why don't you do it on the database? Depending on your table layout it should be quite easy and pretty fast as well.

Comment: should do counting by sql and for this kind of requirement, redis is a very good options

Comment: My experiment shows mysql is easy to write a query but it is very slow on large table. Do count query on a small number of rows is fast but on 1.5B rows is a nightmare, even use indexing and *EXPLAIN* query to make sure it use this index to count.

Comment: What is your schema like? If you're not very experienced with databases, it's unlikely that you'd manage to write an efficient query with a single experiment.

Comment: What is the index of `item_id`? 8 seconds is way way to much.

Comment: @Oleg it is BTREE index, non unique.

Comment: Try with a HASH index